# How can I spray foam open ceiling joists?

Tags: spray-foam

I'm remodeling an old house and have removed the ceiling and old insulation. It's a simple one story structure with a ventilated attic accessible from the exterior. I'd like to do a closed cell spray foam for the ceiling insulation as it's in a damp location near a river. How can I insulate the ceiling joists without having a backing to the cavity readily available?

Should I use plastic sheeting on the backside of the ceiling joists? The ceiling will eventually be small 6" x 6" tiles if that is relevant.

Comment: Why do you need to spray foam the ceiling joists before putting up the ceiling?  What is your plan for fastening the 6x6 tiles?

Comment: The 6x6 will be fastened to 1x2 purlins that run perpendicular to the ceiling joists

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put up the furring strips before you spray foam?

Comment: Is your suggestion to finish the ceiling and then spray it from the backside / e.g. the attic?

Comment: Yes.  I would staple up some plastic sheeting to your furring strips before the tiles (depending how they are fastened in place).